# Jquery dynamic link creation

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink, href, var

Consider the following Jquery code:

```
var previewImage = $('#prev');
var newLink = $('<a/>').attr('href', name);
previewImage.append(newLink);
```

The HTML output is

```
<img src=" " id="prev"/>
<a href=" "></a>
```

The required output is

```
<a href=" "><img src=" " id="prev"/></a>
```

The main problem is that the link is created after the previewImage with id="prev" and I need this image to be inside the link. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the [`wrap()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) method instead of [`append()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

```
var previewImage = $('#prev');
var newLink = $('<a/>').attr('href', name);
previewImage.wrap(newLink);
```